# What does the "Failure to marshal argument(s)" org.jboss.cache.CacheException mean?

Tags: exception, jboss-cache

I get the following exception:

> org.jboss.cache.CacheException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure to
>   marshal argument(s)

We use distributed JBoss cache for our web application (on Tomcat)

I have a strong feeling this is due to bad configuration, but not sure.

**Edit (Correction):**
We use version **3.0.0.GA** of Jboss cache (core)

Comment: Is that the only info it gave you?  No stack trace?

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this? Was it related to the <serialization> section of the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a "swallowed" exception (`NotSerializableException`) that was caught and not logged nor re-thrown by our code, the JBoss exception is general and not necessarily related